# Datatables Sorting For Alphanumeric Column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables for Sorting the ID column.

### ID

### MPT123

### RST789

### AZE190

How can I sort this based on Numeric Values
I tried by doing

```
"columnDefs": [{
            targets: "datatable-nosort",
            orderable: false,
            bsort: false,
            sType: "numeric"
}]
```

But this didn't worked.

Comment: So you want to sort on the number, ignoring the letters before it? Are all IDs of the form AAA000?

Comment: Yes I want to sort on number

Answer (score 1):

I got it working , posting the working code

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"formatted-num-pre": function ( a ) {       
    a = (a === "-" || a === "") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
    return parseFloat( a );
},

"formatted-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return a - b;
},

"formatted-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
    return b - a;
}
} );
```

And call the method as

```
{ "type": "formatted-num", targets: 0 }]
```

Comment: Just FYI, there might be a simpler way using the render function and returning a parseInt of the number part of the string when type = 'sort'. Kudos on finding a solution on your own, though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using natural sorting JS and works great - https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural#Example

Sort data with a mix of numbers and letters naturally. Data can often be a complicated mix of numbers and letters (file names are a common example) and sorting them in a natural manner is quite a difficult problem.

Fortunately a deal of work has already been done in this area by other authors - the following plug-in uses the naturalSort() function by Jim Palmer to provide natural sorting in DataTables.